# How do I write a code for random intervals between a range using numbers in double format?

Tags: java, random, int, double, range

I am trying to write a program that uses *thread.sleep()* which only allows integers. My question is how do I create a program that will grab a random number between the range of 2.5-3.5 seconds (or any random range using double) while using all numbers between that range. I am trying to use this to create a randomized auto-clicker for use of understanding of converting these data types. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is all I have (apologies if this isn't even close I was using all info I could find to help.)

```
    Robot bot = new Robot();

    int rangeMin=2.5, rangeMax=3.5, pressMax = 0, pressMin = 0;

    int randomvalue1 = (r.nextInt() * ((pressMax - pressMin) + 1)) + pressMin;
    int randomValue2 = (r.nextInt() * ((rangeMax - rangeMin) + 1)) + rangeMax;

    for (int x=0; x<3;x++);
        Thread.sleep(randomvalue1);
        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(randomvalue2);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    }
```

Comment: Please do not make edits that invalidate already posted answers.  Edit reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is units of measurement.

Your problem definition speaks about 2.5-3.5 ***seconds***, and you calculate your `randomvalue1` and `randomvalue2` to contain ***seconds***.

The parameter to `Thread.sleep()` must be a ***number of milliseconds***.

Therefore, you need to convert your number of seconds to a number of milliseconds before passing it to `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Nice answer with the details on ms vs seconds.,you got my vote for that.

Comment: Mike, I changed my values to read range in the 1,000's but  when I do that and I look to the outcome of  both random values it's way to large and not even close to the range I am trying to define. Is there in fixes I can make in the  "randomValue" to try and get it to my range.

Comment: I suggested to convert your seconds to milliseconds ***before passing it to `Thread.sleep()`.***  Your edit (which I reverted) follows GhostCat's suggestion instead, which is to do your calculations in milliseconds.  How you are going to do it is up to you, but you really should study the documentation of each function you call.  You were calling `Thread.sleep()` without knowing what kind of parameter it accepts, then you tried calling `Random.nextInt()` without knowing what kind of value it returns.  That's no way to program.  Study the documentation of the functions you call.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things.

Simply start with

```
int delayInMilliSeconds = 2500;
```

Then add a random value between 0 and 1000 to that variable.

And sleep for exactly that number of milliseconds.

Done. You got a delay between 2.5 and 3.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Java code example for approach from GhostCat:

```
Thread.sleep(2500 + ((int) (Math.random() * 1000)));
```

Also look in the Java API documentation, e.g.:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()
- [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))

Answer (score 0):

Finished product, fixed. It makes the length of the click random as well as the wait between individual clicks.

Robot bot = new Robot();

```
    int rangeMin=2445, rangeMax=3550, pressMax = 100, pressMin = 80;

    for (int x=0; x<1620;x++) {
        int randomClick = (60+ (int) (Math.random()*100));
        int randomValue = (1800+ (int) (Math.random()*1000));
        int randomWait = (50+ (int) (Math.random()*100));

        Thread.sleep(randomValue);
        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(randomClick);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        Thread.sleep(randomWait);

        Thread.sleep(randomValue);
        bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(randomClick);
        bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        System.out.println(randomValue);
        System.out.println(randomClick);
        System.out.println(randomWait);
```